# Restful API in web application

Tags: android, rest, web

I'm beginner in web development.
I build accounting android app and MySQL database and connect the app with the MySQL using restful API. My Question is can i connect the web application with MySQL using the same API? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can use it for any app that can use REST Api